# sizeToFit doesn't trigger new line with long words

Tags: ios, tableview, uitableview

I just ran into to strange problem, I have a custom tableview cell with a dynamic height.
While testing this all seemed to work fine, but now that I'm loading real content into it there seem to be some problems.

It appears that some text doesn't trigger a new line in a UILabel

Correct: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/274185/Screen%20Shot%202012-05-09%20at%201.15.21%20PM.png
Wrong: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/274185/Screen%20Shot%202012-05-09%20at%201.15.30%20PM.png

As you can see in the wrong example, the text is pushed to the second line, but the height of the label still only counts one line.

> item.project = @"Another Test Project With Longer Title (Admin / Project Management)";
>
> item.project = @"Test Project (Admin / Project Management)";

The way I calculate the height is like this:

```
// when creating the cell
cell.projectLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
cell.projectLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[cell.projectLabel sizeToFit];

// in heightForRowAtIndexPath()
CGSize projectHeight = [item.project sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

I tried changing the lineBreakMode, but this doesn't seem to help much

EDIT:
It appeared to be a problem when calculation the height of the text, I used a fixed 320 points, which isn't correct, after using the actual width the height was calculated correctly.

```
CGSize projectHeight = [item.project sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(cell.projectLabel.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* that sizeToFit only sizes the view down.
You should set the frame of your label to be high enough for two lines and then call sizeToFit. That will shrink the label when the text is only one line but keep its height when the text is two lines.

Comment: In Interface Builder the frame of my label is heigh enough to fit multiple lines. But as you can see from the screenshot it only happens in some cases, which makes me think it has something to do with the lineBreakMode

Comment: Test `UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap` to see if that is true

Comment: Same problem, when I output the height it gives 32px for the first one and the other one only gives 16px. Strange...

Comment: Is that the height of the label or the height of the row? What is the height of the row compared to the height of the label?

Comment: The height of the row is dynamic, for example in the row of the last screenshot, the row is 131px, the label is 16px, in the first screenshot the row is 189px and the label is 32px

Comment: It appeared to be a problem when calculation the height of the text, I used a fixed 320 points, which isn't correct, after using the actual width the height was calculated correctly.

    CGSize projectHeight = [item.project sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(cell.projectLabel.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

Comment: It did, because the height of the text was calculated based on the text, not the actual label.